# How to remove values that do not meet condition from pandas data frame column?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I remove under age rows from this data set?

**Original dataset**

```
ID                 age
xqd26543231        12
xqd22222231        29
xqd88823231        64
```

**What I tried?**

```
#remove under age users
eligibleAge = myDataFrame['Age']>18
myDataFrame['Age'] = myDataFrame[eligibleAge]
```

**Unexpected result**

```
ID                 age
xqd26543231        xqd26543231
xqd22222231        xqd22222231
xqd88823231        xqd88823231
```

**What I  expect**

```
ID                 age
xqd22222231        29
xqd88823231        64
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just do `myDataFrame = myDataFrame[myDataFrame['Age']>18]`

In your code,
`myDataFrame['Age'] = myDataFrame[eligibleAge]`
right side has different length as left size you are assigning to, and also you are assigning a dataframe onto a serie.

Comment: do you know if there is any way I could you np.where() as in ```https://realpython.com/python-data-cleaning-numpy-pandas/```

Comment: `np.where` just returns you the index of where the condition evaluates to True, so you could use it with iloc in pandas, `myDataFrame.iloc[np.where(myDataFrame['Age']>18)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`df.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) here.

```
df.query('age>18')
            ID  age
1  xqd22222231   29
2  xqd88823231   64
```